# Exporting the RouterModule?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

In this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fauth%2Fauth-routing.module.ts) the `auth.routing.ts` module imports `RouterModule` and uses it to configure the route for the `LoginComponent`.  It then also exports the `RouterModule` again like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Just curious whether it's necessary, since it seems like the RouterModule has to be globally available within the App?

Comment: Yes, this is necessary. Only the service is globally available. Each module needs to import RouterModule in order to use the router directives (such as `routerLink` and `routerOutlet`) When you use a "routing module", you then need to export it so that it is available to the app module when you import the "routing module". Make sense?

Comment: The reason I think it's strange is that we have to export the `RouterModule` again is that we are only calling `forChild` on it, which is a static method and thus available across the entire runtime and it has to talk to the global `Router` service instance in order for `forChild` to do it's job, so since this is the case it seems odd that we are reexporting ...In order for the application to work the core has to import `RouterModule` at least once, so I would think that all other sub modules would only have to import it and call static methods on it, which then talk to the global instance.

Comment: You could definitely try it out without it. But I'd bet you'd get one of those `routerLink is not a valid property of anchor` type of error messages because it won't be able to find the directives. Think of each module as a box containing a set of components, directives and pipes. Everything that those component, directives, and pipes need must be imported into that same box (module). Except of course services, which are registered with an application injector and don't need to be defined in a module.

Comment: Yes that part makes sense.  I understand having to import the things the module needs so that we have all the parts ready to go essentially.  The reexporting part / requirement seems strange because it sort of implies that we will be importing `RouterModule` from this sub module, but AFAIK we import `RouterModule` always from `@angular/Router`.  I'll play around with it and see what the behavior is.  It would great if Angular could come up with a more DRY / Annotation based approach around perhaps the regular Typescript imports.

Comment: Yes, and that is where it is confusing. Importing `RouterModule` from `@angular/router` is doing the **TypeScript** importing. Adding something to the imports array is pulling the library into the "box" of everything that the components, directives, and pipes need.

Comment: Seems like the `Router` is the primary driver of how Angular compiles the modules so hopefully we can get some additional flags that `Mark` whether the path is a lazy path, prefetched, etc. together with some static code analysis to automatically generate the modules for us, and we can kiss modules goodbye.

Comment: There is discussion of making Angular modules (ngModule) optional when Ivy is released: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27481

Comment: Sweet!  I have filed some feature requests related to this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/created_by/oleersoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exporting the `RouterModule` is not required.  [Here is a stackblitz demo showing that the creation and use of the `AuthRoutingModule` without an export of the `RouterModule`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store-74c17d?file=example-app/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts).